# Python: Only keep lines with more than 3 words if characters in words are alphabetic

Tags: python-3.x, text, isalpha, text-normalization

the following code 1 allows me to only keep lines with more than 3 words. In some lines of my large text document, there are lines with non-alphabetic characters and 3 words or less which I would like to exclude as well from my cleaned list of lines. When using *.isalpha()* in code 2 it seems to not go line by line anymore when counting words in a line. I'm new to Python and would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me. The lines I want to keep would be `lines_clean = ["This is some text as an", "what I want to"]`

Code 1:

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import line_tokenize, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
f = "This is some text as an \n example of 5\n what I want to \n achieve \n with my #$ code"
lines = line_tokenize(f)
lines_clean = []
for line in lines:
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    n_words = len(words)
    if n_words >=3:
        lines_clean.append(line)
print(lines_clean)
```

Code 2 (not working as intended):

```
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import line_tokenize, sent_tokenize, word_tokenize
f = "This is some text as an \n example of 5\n what I want to \n achieve \n with my #$ code"
lines = line_tokenize(f)
lines_clean = []
alpha_only = []
for line in lines:
    words = word_tokenize(line)
    for word in words:
        if word.isalpha():
            alpha_only.append(word)     
    n_words = len(alpha_only)
    if n_words >=3:
        lines_clean.append(line)
print(lines_clean)
```

Comment: You need to reset the list alpha_only for each line.   move the code line 'alpha_only=[]' to the first line in the for

Comment: Thank you so much Neriya Bar-lev for the quick and helpful reply. It worked!